# How to specify width of React Datepicker popper width to take 100% of the parent?

Tags: css, reactjs, datepicker, popper.js, react-datepicker

I'm using [ReactDatepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) and massively impressed by the number of customizations they offer right off the box, thank you very much for that.

Here is a real world problem I'm struggling with. As you can see there are three columns:

1. choose a show
2. pick a date
3. find tickets

[image]

Ideally, I would like datepicker to have a width equal to the width of the column.

There is some documentation provided:

- https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-28
- https://popper.js.org/popper-documentation.html

But maybe there is a magical modifier allowing me to say *"take 100% width of the parent container"*?

---

Currently I can modify the size by changing the width of an individual item:

> $datepicker__item-size: 1.7rem !default;

https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/src/stylesheets/variables.scss#L16

But modifying that doesn't work for me - the column width as defined as `%` of the parent.

Comment: You can see, the option that this plugin offer your, you have for sure an className for overide the default css

Comment: I have imported all the `.scss` files from `node_modules` into my code because of the order how `$variables` were included... I can modify CSS but the question remains - how? The way how the popper is appearing, it's non-obvious how to make it look the way I want...